# Free SVN but not OpenSource

Tags: svn

I'm looking for an svn to host code but I'm not interested in sharing it. I've been reading through the jungle of info on svn hosting here and although I have a better grasp on it now I still haven't found any free svn for non-opensource projects.

Can any one recommend a free svn service allowing multiple users for non-opensource projects?

EDIT:
Just found this great link:
[SVN hosting comparison chart](http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com/)
Thank you,
Rd42

Comment: What's with the -1 vote?  That seemed like a valid question that wasn't specifically described in other svn posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one that is really famous, is listed on the Tigris website

http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download

free for 1 user and 1 repository ,100 mb of disk space

Answer (score 2):

[assembla](http://www.assembla.com/) offers svn and git for free and not public or open source.

Comment: is now PUBLIC for free version

Comment: Is not free anymore. I've been working with, but they don't allow me to commit anymore , so **It's not for free anymore **

Comment: Yeah, they only seem to give you a trial for like 30 days.

Comment: Deveo https://deveo.com still offers free svn hosting up until 1GB with no user, repository or project limits.